# jquery to convert date from mm/dd/yy to yyyy-dd-mm

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I'm receiving an ajax response that has a date in the format mm/dd/yy. How can I convert this to the format yyyy-mm-dd using jquery? Does jquery have an internal function to do this?

Comment: If you're only getting 2 year digits, how are you going to return 4 if you don't know whether it's 1900's or 2000's?

Comment: @mVChr it's lame but generally you assume that 2-digit numbers greater than something like 90 (depends on the application) are in the 1900s, and 2-digit years smaller than that are in this century.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple with no checking of the input (JavaScript, no jQuery):

```
var d        = '01/25/90';   // as an example
var yy       = d.substr(6,2);
var newdate  = (yy < 90) ? '20' + yy : '19' + yy;
    newdate += '-' + d.substr(0,2) + '-' + d.substr(3,2); //1990-01-25
```

Answer (score 2):

That sort of thing is not what jQuery is designed to facilitate. The jQuery library is primarily about DOM manipulation, with various concessions made to code structure convenience.

What you need to do is split up the incoming address *as text* and either reconstruct it as a compliant JavaScript parseable date, or else just get the year, month, and day from the string and use the javascript "Date()" constructor that takes those as numeric values.This code will give you a Date from your format:

This code will give you a Date from your format:

```
function toDate(str) {
  var rv = null;
  str.replace(/^(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\$/, function(d, yy, mm, dd) {
    if (!d) throw "Bad date: " + str;
    yy = parseInt(yy, 10);
    yy = yy < 90 ? 2000 + yy : 1900 + yy;
    rv = new Date(yy, parseInt(mm, 10) - 1, parseInt(dd, 10));
    return null;
  });
  return rv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){   

        $("#date").change(function(){
            var $d = $(this).val();  
            var $yy = $d.substr(6,4);
            var $dd = $d.substr(3,2);
            var $mm = $d.substr(0,2);
            var $newdate = $yy + '-' + $mm + '-' + $dd; 
            $("#date").val($newdate);
        });
    })

</script>
```

---

Comment: Your answer should contains an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.

Comment: You can use this when you have calendar picker whatever you picked date it will change its format to yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Dates</h2>

<p>Output :</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

const inputval = '121212';
console.log(inputval.value)
const transDtDD =  Number(inputval.slice(0,2))
const transDtMM =  Number(inputval.slice(2,4))
const transDtYY = Number(inputval.slice(4,6))

var dt = new Date();
  dt.setMonth(transDtMM-1);
  
const transDtMMM = dt.toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'short' })

const dateVal = new Date(transDtDD+'/'+transDtMMM+'/'+transDtYY)

const transDate = dateVal.toLocaleDateString()

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = transDate;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I worked out the option to return DD/MM/YYYY from DDMMYY